# Can't access classes name added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

I've added an `img` tag with class name into a `div` element with jQuery:

```
$("#uploadedimage").html("<img src='test.jpg' id='imgtest' class='imgtest'>");
```

After that, I'm not able to access it (`imgtest`) with jQuery by its `class`:

```
$(".imgtest").click(function()
{
      alert("hi!");
});
```

or by its `id`:

```
$("#imgtest").click(function()
{
      alert("hi!");
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to bind event before element added? Your question missing context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").on("click","#imgtest" ,function(){
      alert("hi!");
});
```

OR

```
$("body").on("click",".imgtest" ,function(){
      alert("hi!");
});
```

Comment: Ha, 3 seconds apart - you are quick +1

Answer (score 1):

Because you added it dynamically, it is not in the DOM. See [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You will need to capture it like this:

```
 $("body").on("click", ".imgtest", function(){
  alert("hi!");
 });
```

You could swap out `body` for a different element that was present in the DOM

Comment: You was faster than me because of your explanation. +1